# Add new columns of random numbers to existing table

Tags: sas

I'm totally new to SAS. 
I would like to add two columns of randomly generated 0s and 1s to my existing table.

Can anyone give me some feedback?

I know how to do this in R but absolutely not in SAS.

Thank you in advance

Comment: what have you tried so far?  have you googled sas random numbers? To update a table look at proc sql.

Comment: How would you do it in R? If we can help you translate that code into SAS that might help.

Comment: are you looking for `rantbl ()` function?

Comment: Looks like he never read any SAS tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the RAND() function and can specify the BERNOULLI treatment. I've also included CALL STREAMINIT() which is the random seed.

```
data want;
   set have;

   call streaminit(123);

   new_var = rand('bernoulli', 0.5);
run;
```

More details here: https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/08/24/how-to-generate-random-numbers-in-sas.html